# Aggregate data and exclude duplicates in one column

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to simplify an analysis that used two `SQL` queries, down to one. In doing so, I joined biomass data to the size class data within the single `SQL` query, which creates duplicates. This is because biomass is already a sum, and is the total biomass for `taxa_name` within each `site`, i.e. it is a one-to-many value in my new table.

To get away from 2 `SQL` queries, I've done the work in two `data.table` manipulations and a join at the end. An alternative is to do calculations and remove duplicates twice. Is there a way to avoid either of these just by using `data.table`?

#### Example data

```
testdf <- structure(list(spcode = c(10008L, 10008L, 10002L, 10002L, 10006L, 10008L, 10008L, 10002L, 10002L, 10011L, 10002L, 10002L, 10006L, 10006L, 10006L), abundance = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L), biomass = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), size_class = c(21L, 20L, 14L, 10L, 14L, 21L, 23L, 16L, 13L, 17L, 12L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 11L), site = c(907L, 907L, 907L, 907L, 907L, 914L, 914L, 914L, 914L, 914L, 910L, 910L, 910L, 910L, 910L), taxa_name = c("Hippoglossina stomata", "Hippoglossina stomata", "Symphurus atricaudus", "Symphurus atricaudus", "Microstomus pacificus", "Hippoglossina stomata", "Hippoglossina stomata", "Symphurus atricaudus", "Symphurus atricaudus", "Parophrys vetulus", "Symphurus atricaudus", "Symphurus atricaudus", "Microstomus pacificus", "Microstomus pacificus", "Microstomus pacificus"), lnXabun = c(21L, 20L, 14L, 10L, 14L, 21L, 23L, 16L, 26L, 17L, 12L, 5L, 9L, 40L, 22L)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00362498>)
```

#### Calculations

```
# biomass
bm <- testdf
bm <- bm[, .(site = unique(site)),
   by = list(spcode, taxa_name, biomass)][, totbm := sum(biomass), by = list(spcode)][!duplicated(spcode), c(1,5)]

    > bm
   spcode totbm
1:  10008   0.5
2:  10002   0.3
3:  10006   0.6
4:  10011   0.5
```

Abundance is done next, then the two are joined on `spcode`.

```
# abundance
testdf <- testdf[, .(totabn = sum(lnXabun), n = sum(abundance), minlngth = min(size_class), maxlngth = max(size_class)),
      by = list(spcode, taxa_name)]

# join
testdf[bm, on = 'spcode', bm := i.totbm]

> testdf
   spcode             taxa_name totabn n minlngth maxlngth  bm
1:  10008 Hippoglossina stomata     85 4       20       23 0.5
2:  10002  Symphurus atricaudus     83 7        5       16 0.3
3:  10006 Microstomus pacificus     85 8        9       14 0.6
4:  10011     Parophrys vetulus     17 1       17       17 0.5
```

The above output of `testdf` is my desired output. My other attempt relies on two `!duplicated` calls. In my head, I want to be able to use `[, totbm := sum(biomass), by = list(unique(site), spcode)]`, within the abundance calculation, but that doesn't work.

```
testdf[, .(site = (site), biomass = biomass, totabn = sum(lnXabun), n = sum(abundance), minlngth = min(size_class), maxlngth = max(size_class)), by = list(spcode, taxa_name)][, totbm := sum(biomass), by = list(unique(site), spcode)]
Error in `[.data.table`(testdf[, .(site = (site), biomass = biomass, totabn = sum(lnXabun),  : The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length (3,15). Each must be length 15; the same length as there are rows in x (after subsetting if i is provided).
```

Alternative method:

```
alt <- bm[, .(site = site, taxa_name = taxa_name, biomass = biomass, totabn = sum(lnXabun), n = sum(abundance), minlngth = min(size_class), maxlngth = max(size_class)),
by = list(spcode)]
alt <- alt[!duplicated(alt, by = c("site", "spcode"))]
alt[, totbm := sum(biomass), by = list(spcode)]
alt[!duplicated(alt, by = "spcode"), c(1,3,5:9)]
```

Comment: Your `biomass` calculation first adds an `n` that is then used for nothing?

Comment: Yes, sorry that was a relic that was missed. I'll remove it to avoid confusion.

Comment: Do you save a lot of time/processing going from 2 to 1 SQL queries? I would recommend against building a table that has redundancies (for example, the fact taht taxa_name = 'Hippoglossina stomata' and site = 907 always goes with biomass 0.2 is repeated in testdf), especially if other columns, such as lnXabun, don't have the same redundant pattern, and there is aggregation involved. You may be able to find a solution for this particular problem, but down the road it will almost certainly trip you up.

Comment: @Andreas It saves a small amount of time (~30s), since this is something that is done on yearly data, but if it risks anything, keeping it in separate queries and calculations can be done for data integrity.

Answer (score 3):

Like I mentioned in my comment, I'm not a fan of the table with the data redundancies, but here is one way to solve the problem. Basically, instead of using some sort of 'unique' function, give in index number by group of site/taxa_name so that you can set all but the first biomass value to 0. Then a sum by spcode/taxa_name should work fine. This of course assumes that a set of site/taxa_name values corresponds to exactly one biomass value.

```
testdf <- data.table(spcode = c(10008L, 10008L, 10002L, 10002L, 10006L, 10008L, 10008L, 10002L, 10002L, 10011L, 10002L, 10002L, 10006L, 10006L, 10006L), 
                         abundance = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L), 
                         biomass = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), 
                         size_class = c(21L, 20L, 14L, 10L, 14L, 21L, 23L, 16L, 13L, 17L, 12L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 11L), 
                         site = c(907L, 907L, 907L, 907L, 907L, 914L, 914L, 914L, 914L, 914L, 910L, 910L, 910L, 910L, 910L), 
                         taxa_name = c("Hippoglossina stomata", "Hippoglossina stomata", "Symphurus atricaudus", "Symphurus atricaudus", "Microstomus pacificus", "Hippoglossina stomata", "Hippoglossina stomata", "Symphurus atricaudus", "Symphurus atricaudus", "Parophrys vetulus", "Symphurus atricaudus", "Symphurus atricaudus", "Microstomus pacificus", "Microstomus pacificus", "Microstomus pacificus"), 
                         lnXabun = c(21L, 20L, 14L, 10L, 14L, 21L, 23L, 16L, 26L, 17L, 12L, 5L, 9L, 40L, 22L))

testdf[, biomassIdx := 1:.N, by = c('site', 'taxa_name')]
testdf[biomassIdx > 1, biomass := 0]
testdf[, .(tatabn = sum(lnXabun), n = sum(abundance), minlngth = min(size_class), maxlngth = max(size_class) , bm = sum(biomass)),
        by = list(spcode, taxa_name)]
```

Comment: u can also combine the first 2 lines of code into `testdf[rowid(site, taxa_name) > 1L, biomass := 0]`

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, you're complicating yourself a bit.
Just do a distinct and a summary:

```
bm <- testdf[, .SD[1L], by = list(spcode, taxa_name, biomass, site) # distinct
             ][, .(totbm = sum(biomass)), by = "spcode"] # summary
```

Comment: This definitely simplifies the biomass calculation, but still requires a join. I was trying to figure out if/how you could do both operations without a join or an explicit `!duplicated`.

Comment: @Anonymouscoward oh, that does make it more complicated.